# object keys to array, preserving order

Tags: javascript

This is my object:

```
const small = {
    'S': 'CS3',
    'D': 'EB3',
    'G': 'FS3',
    'H': 'AB3',
    'J': 'BB3',
    '2': 'CS4',
    '3': 'EB4',
    '5': 'FS4',
    '6': 'AB4',
    '7': 'BB4'
}
```

I am trying to get an array of keys, IN THE ORIGINAL ORDER, and neither `Object.keys(small)` nor `(for const key in small)` work, it keeps reordering the array with the integers first. How can I get an array of these keys in this order?

Comment: You can't. Objects are inherently unordered. If you care about order, you should use an array of single key-value pairs instead.

Comment: There are rules for how object property names are ordered, but they're not under your control. Numeric keys always come first.

Comment: https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/